# Can any one tell me what will be the exact URL for payflowpro now , the Url "https://payflowpro.paypal.com" does not work for me now

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curl, paypal

## Issue "Curl::Err::SSLConnectError"

Can any one tell me what will be the exact URL for `Payflowpro` now , 
the Url  "https://payflowpro.paypal.com" does not work for me now.
It was working fine before but for some reason it gives me an error now.

### Code in Lib file

---

### Code in module

```
post_contents =  Curl::PostField.content('TRXTYPE', 'S'),
                         Curl::PostField.content('TENDER', 'C'),
                         Curl::PostField.content('AMT', amount),
                         Curl::PostField.content('ORDERID', order),
                         Curl::PostField.content('CURRENCY', PAYPAL_CONFIG[:currency]),
                         Curl::PostField.content('CREATESECURETOKEN', 'Y'),
                         Curl::PostField.content('SECURETOKENID', secure_random),
                         Curl::PostField.content('PARTNER', PAYPAL_CONFIG[:partner]),
                         Curl::PostField.content('VENDOR', 'abababa'),
                         Curl::PostField.content('USER', 'abababa'),
                         Curl::PostField.content('PWD', 'abababa')
```

### Logs Details

```
Started POST "/__better_errors/45429440/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-20 12:24:16 +0500
TRXTYPE=S
TENDER=C
AMT=5.99
ORDERID=1421738848U1
CURRENCY=USD
CREATESECURETOKEN=Y
SECURETOKENID=****
PARTNER=Paypal
VENDOR=****
USER=*****
PWD=*****
 Rebuilt URL to: https://payflowpro.paypal.com/
 Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
   Trying 173.0.82.162...
 Connected to payflowpro.paypal.com (173.0.82.162) port 443 (#2)
 successfully set certificate verify locations:
   CAfile: none
 CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
 error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
 Closing connection 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the change announced by PayPal.

Whoever is using the older SSLv3 needs to check their implementation of update their code to use the TLS version for curl.

PayPal provides info in this [link](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/439486/1415754263/redirect/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDIxNzQ1MjUwL3NpZC9HN25wdFZjbQ==/filename/Poodle%20SSL%203%200%20Vulnerability%20-%20Payflow%20Response%20Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

That is still the correct endpoint.  It looks like something going on with your DNS based on the message stating "NOT found in DNS cache."

You could try changing to use different DNS servers and see if that resolves your issue.  For example, you could use Google's DNS servers or OpenDNS.

Google's DNS servers are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Open DNS is 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220.

Depending on your router you may be able to update the DNS server there, or you may need to do it from your local NIC card properties.

Comment: Thanks andrew  let me try Thanks

Comment: Something else is a miss as the server we have is a amazon based server and that is throwing this error. And we are also getting this error on our local machines.

Comment: Actually i am unable to direct open this url "https://payflowpro.paypal.com"
Are you able to open this?

Comment: Seems the issue might be because of the POODLE SSL 3.0 Vulnerability change that PayPal mentions in their recent notice. Any suggestions on how to resolve that.

Comment: You just need to make sure that your cURL/OpenSSL install supports the TLS protocol.

Comment: andrew just got it need to change 
curl.ssl_version = Curl::CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1